# Postgresql function to calculate moving average

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a function to calculate the moving average of values stored in postgresql table.

I know how to calculate this mobile average inside a query using frame window, for example :

```
select val, avg(val) over (order by... rows between current row and n following)
```

But, for some reasons, I really need to have a plpgsql function calculating this mobile average, in order to be able to query, for example :

```
select moving_average_function(val, p) from ....
```

to get the moving average of data on a p period basis.

And here comes my problem... How to pass the set of p values to the function, in order to achieve the calculation of the average of those p values ?....

Let's take an example :

```
Table my_data :

| id | val |
|----+-----|
| 1  | 10  |
| 2  | 12  |
| 3  | 8   |
| 4  | 7   |
| 5  | 9   |
| 6  | 8   |
| 7  | 13  |
```

I want to create the function ma_func(value, period) that will produce following results :

```
select id, val, ma_func(val, 3 order by id) from my_date order by id;

| id | val | ma_func |
|----+-----+---------|
| 1  | 10  | 10      | => average(10)
| 2  | 12  | 11      | => average(12, 10)
| 3  | 8   | 10      | => average(8, 12, 10)
| 4  | 7   | 9       | => average(7, 8, 12)
| 5  | 9   | 8       | => average(9, 7, 8)
| 6  | 8   | 8       | => average(8, 9, 7)
| 7  | 13  | 10      | => average(13, 8, 9)
etc, etc...
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I'm on this subject for quite a long time now and do not progress at all !
Thanks

Comment: That cannot be done, because the function wouldn't know anything about the table. Use a window function. Maybe explain why you think that a window function cannot be used, so you can be helped over that obstacle.

Comment: In fact, the function I really need to create is much more complicated than a simple moving average. It has many CASEs and other tests specific to business logic. In addition, it is used hundreds of times in different parts of the application.
So, of course, I could edit the hundreds of queries directly. But using a function would be much simpler!
Thx for help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about postgre sql and for sql server 2012 and above:

```
CREATE TABLE avg1 (
  id int,
  val int
);

INSERT INTO avg1
  VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO avg1
  VALUES (2, 12);
INSERT INTO avg1
  VALUES (3, 8);
INSERT INTO avg1
  VALUES (4, 7);
INSERT INTO avg1
  VALUES (5, 9);
INSERT INTO avg1
  VALUES (6, 8);
INSERT INTO avg1
  VALUES (7, 13);

SELECT
  id,
  val,
  AVG(CAST(val AS decimal(18, 2))) OVER (
  ORDER BY id DESC ROWS BETWEEN
  CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)

FROM avg1
ORDER BY id
```

Saravanan

Comment: Yes, I know how to perform the calculation using partition window. It's roughly the same syntax using PostgreSQL. But, what I'm looking for is to do it using an User Defined Function, as the real calculation is much more complicated than a simple average (business logic inside) and have to be implemented in hundreds of parts of the application.